# create pretty PDF report file in R

Tags: r, pdf

I am done with all analysis and would like to output a summary report in only one pdf file. The first page, I would like to write bold and big "Report" in the middle. Second page, I would like to insert a table(I have this data frame in R) with a very short table title. The rest pages are my graphs. One page, one graph.

Currently,my pdf file only have four pages. Any idea that I can the first page and second page. Thank you!

```
pdf()
plot1  #page 1
plot2  #page 2
plot3  #page 3
plot4  #page 4
dev.off()
```

Comment: I would recommend looking into `knitr`. It may be overkill for the report you describe here, but it would be worth learning should you have future reports like this.

Comment: Have you ever heard about [R Markdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com) and [Knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/)? check them out.

Comment: @CephBirk @ SabDeM I never use Markdown and Knitr before. I will ck out. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if the first page with vertically aligned title is possible in Markdown. For this you might be better off using the LaTeX variant of knitr although it's got a steeper learning curve.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a Sweave version of what you want:

```sweave
\documentclass[a4paper, titlepage]{article}
\title{Report}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

\makeatletter
\vspace*{\fill}
{\centering\Huge\bfseries\@title\par}
\vspace*{\fill}
\makeatother

\newpage

\subsection*{Table}
<<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
library(xtable)
print(xtable(data.frame(x = rnorm(20), y = rnorm(20))), floating = FALSE)
@

\newpage

\subsection*{Plot 1}

<<plot1, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
plot(rnorm(100))
@
\newpage

\subsection*{Plot 2}

<<plot2, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
plot(rnorm(100))
@
\newpage

\subsection*{Plot 3}

<<plot3, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
plot(rnorm(100))
@
\newpage

\subsection*{Plot 4}

<<plot4, fig=TRUE, echo=FALSE>>=
plot(rnorm(100))
@

\end{document}
```

You should save it as "MyReport.Rnw" and then can compile it using

```
Sweave("MyReport.Rnw")
tools::texi2pdf("MyReport.tex")
```

RStudio has a great interface for compiling PDFs from .Rnw files. You can also `knitr` with LaTeX formatted files (as opposed to RMarkdown). You'll need to run the above file through `knitr::Sweave2knitr("MyReport.Rnw")` first. You can even use a LaTeX editor Lyx with knitr (see http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/).